# MATLAB - finding the index of a string in a vector

Tags: matlab, printf

I am trying to print out a very simple table (using fprintf) showing statistics on a set of data I've acquired.

I'm new to Matlab, but - me being used to Java - I think this should work...

```
Labels = ['Max','Min','Mean','Median','Std. Dev.','Tol. Range'];
for i = 1:6
    fprintf('| %c | %4.3f | %4.3f |\n', Labels(i), unmodVals(i), modVals(i));
end
```

But it doesn't work. :(

For some reason, array indexing for strings doesn't work the same way as it does in Java so i'm completely lost.

it ends up printing out something like:

```
| M |    ####    |    ####    |
| a |    ####    |    ####    |
| x |    ####    |    ####    |
| M |    ####    |    ####    |
| i |    ####    |    ####    |
| n |    ####    |    ####    |
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Character arrays work a little differently in MATLAB. `Labels` is not a 1x6 array of strings like you're expecting it to be; the line you have is equivalent to

```
Labels = strcat('Max','Min','Mean','Median','Std. Dev.','Tol. Range');
```

So it's a 1x35 array of characters, and you're indexing into it one character at a time. Change `Labels` to a cell array of strings as below. You must index into it using braces `{ }` instead of parentheses `( )`, and change the corresponding `fprintf` format specifier to `%s` (`%c` is for printing characters)

```
Labels = {'Max','Min','Mean','Median','Std. Dev.','Tol. Range'};

for i = 1:6
    fprintf('| %s | %4.3f | %4.3f |\n', Labels{i}, unmodVals(i), modVals(i));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing strings in an array called `Labels`. In MATLAB, when you write `['a', 'bc']`, it concatenates two strings and produces `abc`. Therefore, you should use cell arrays to store strings of different sizes.

```
Labels = {'Max','Min','Mean','Median','Std. Dev.','Tol. Range'}; %notice the curly braces.

%generating random values of `unmodVals` and `modVals`
unmodVals=randi(1000,[1 6]);
modVals=randi(1000,[1 6]);
for i = 1:6
    fprintf('| %s | %4.3f | %4.3f |\n', Labels{i}, unmodVals(i), modVals(i)); %notice change    from `%c` to `%s`, c stands for charater, s for string.
end
```

Note: If you see how your `Label` variable looks, you will see this:

```
Labels = MaxMinMeanMedianStd. Dev.Tol. Range
```